# 3D model sharing

Tags: ros, cad

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone

I was looking for 3D CAD files of sensors and hardware used with the ROS framework, but not many manufactures have 3D models for download.

So I started trying to search for each sensor:
http://wiki.ros.org/Sensors
But I'm interested in getting everything for designing robots - so motor controllers, motors, sensors, etc used with ROS and has ROS packages available for use.

And Some I find, some I don't when going through google, grabcad etc

So I wanted to know if people would like to share 3D models for robotics?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249962/3d-model-sharing/) by [Dynamitetalks](https://answers.ros.org/users/6157/dynamitetalks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2016-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I tried to find all 1D,2D,3D sensors and collect them, I found some of them
from:  http://wiki.ros.org/Sensors

If someone is interested it is available for download from my google drive:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByOsJfCUaf3sTDlCOE15MWxDdTA/view?usp=sharing

I hope someone will share other files.

---

Originally posted by [Dynamitetalks](https://answers.ros.org/users/6157/dynamitetalks/) with karma: 61 on 2016-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) on 2016-12-13**:
Ya. It will be a good contribution to the community. Keep up your work. May be try to add it in wiki.